# creation of accounts for each users in mysql / phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am planning to create mysql accounts for each of my web devs and build their own databases. I need these devs to have accounts to access their own phpmyadmin where they can manipulate their own sets of databases.

I am kind of new to web services deployment, so should this setup be configured in phpmyadmin or in mysql?

Will this kind of deployment need web management like cpanel?

I hope you can enlighten me with this.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use Synchronize tab:

- All of your web devs would Synchronize databases they work on to their local machines
- When the work is done, they just synchronize back to server

For this to work, you need to add:

```
`$cfg['AllowArbitraryServer'] = true;`
```

somewhere at beginning of the:

```
`/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`
```

Ofcours you will have to add users and grant them privileges on databases they will gona use on server.

More info [here](http://toyhouse.cc/profiles/blogs/synchronize-databases-by-phpmyadmin)